# How to compute the subset which is not a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question was "compute the subset which is not subspace" and I can't understand the question.

Does it mean "show why the sets are subset which is not subspace"?

Here is an example of the question.

{$f(x) \in P(\Bbb R)|f(1)=0$}

How can I compute?

Comment: Is this the direct wording of the question or a translation?

Comment: Yes the question is "Compute the subset of R3 which is not subspace of P(R)<=3" @SeanRoberson

Comment: I have a really hard time believing this is the actual wording of the question. This is extremely sloppy, and almost nonsensical. If this really is word-for-word everything and exactly what is written, then (i) if it’s a textbook, stop reading it, (ii) if it’s from an assignment, ask your prof to clarify what exactly they mean.